# Plotly Indicator how to show full number

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a problem with an indicator from Plotly, below is my code:

```
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 32000,
    number = {'prefix': "zł"},
    delta = {'position': "top", 'reference': 32000, "valueformat": "f"},
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "lightgray")

fig.show()
```

Code works but the value is being showed in the rounded way with "k". How can I visualize the full number?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, set the value notation to the numeric notation. I referred to the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/indicator/#data-cards--big-numbers).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 32000,
    number = {'prefix': "zł","valueformat": ".0f"},
    delta = {'position': "top", 'reference': 32000, "valueformat": "f"},
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "lightgray")

fig.show()
```

[image]